# Correction of interpretations of a sentence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the sentence $\phi = \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z(p(x,y)\land p(z,y)\land(p(x,z)\rightarrow p(z,x))),$ and the following interpretations, and the task is to evaluate $\phi$'s true value in each:

a) The interpretation $M$ has as its domain the set of natural numbers, and $ p^M = \{(m,n)| m < n\} $

b)The interpretation $M'$ has as its domain the set of natural numbers, and $ p^{M'} =\{(m,2m)|\;m\;is\;a\;natural\;number\;\} $

c)The interpretation $M''$ has as its domain the set of natural numbers, and $ p^{M''} =\{(m,n)|m < n+1\}.$

I have provided some proofs, however I don't know if they are correct and if they are sufficiently formalized:

a)
[image]
b)
[image]
c)
[image]

##### Edit

a) For any x, take y=x+1 and z=x, and that will make everything true.

b) For any x, take y=2x and z=x, then everything will be true.

c) For any x, take y=x and z=x, then everything will be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes little sense to assign a truth-value to a formula like $p(x,y)$, because in this formula, $x$ and $y$ are free variables, and you only obtain a sentence once those variables get quantified.

In fact, it crucially depends on *how* the variables are quantified. For example, if we take the first interpretation $M$, then a sentence like:

$$\forall x \forall y \ p(x,y)$$

comes to mean:

"Every natural number is smaller than all natural numbers"

which is clearly False.

But if you use existentials, you get:

$$\exists x \exists y \ p(x,y)$$

which would mean "some number is smaller than some natural number"

which is True.

And, if you use a mix of quantifiers, then:

$$\forall x \exists y \ p(x,y)$$

means: "Every natural number is smaller than some natural number", which is True (indeed, for every natural number $xZ$, I can pick some natural $y$ (e.g. we can pick $y=x+1$) such that $x<y$

but:

$$\exists x \forall y \ p(x,y)$$

would mean: "There is some natural number that is smaller than all natural numbers"

which is False: even if you pick $0$, that is still not smaller than all natural numbers, since $0$ is not smaller than itself (if you have the natural numbers start with $1$, then we can point out that $1$ is not smaller than $1$)

So, long story short:  you need to find the value of the *whole* sentence $\phi = \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z(p(x,y)\land p(z,y)\land(p(x,z)\rightarrow p(z,x)))$ given the 3 different interpretations.

Comment: Yes, @Bram28, I am a beginner... Could you make a more clear response please?

Comment: @Breno  Hmm, what I said is pretty basic. Again, you need to quantify every variable before it becomes a sentence, and only sentences have a truth-value. So, you cannot say that $p(x,y)$ is True or False, or $P(x,z) \to p(z,x)$: they have free (unquantified) variables, so those are not sentences, and we cannot say whether they are true or false. So the only thing you can evaluate here is $\phi$ as a whole.  I gave you some example of how to interpret sentences and evaluate them with some different quantifiers, but I assume your book has examples like that as well.

Comment: Oh, I understand you, but what I meant was to get the value for each of those three propositions and assume the whole was true only if all of the propositions in the conjunctions were true

Comment: @Breno  Ah, I see what you're trying to do!  You effectively try to equate $\phi = \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z(p(x,y)\land p(z,y)\land(p(x,z)\rightarrow p(z,x)))$ with $\forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ p(x,y) \land \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ p(z,y) \land \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ (p(x,z)\rightarrow p(z,x))$ , and we can evaluate each of the three conjuncts in the latter sentence.  OK, unfortunately that doesn't work:  You can only pick $y$ and $z$ in the original sentence $\phi$ once, but in the new sentences, you can pick different $y$ and $z$ for each of the three conjuncts. (cont'd)

Comment: Could you suggest me a text book which has explanation and example on how to solve those interpretations, please?

Comment: ... so, that makes the sentence $\forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ p(x,y) \land \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ p(z,y) \land \forall _x\exists_y\exists_z \ (p(x,z)\rightarrow p(z,x))$ *not* equivalent to the original $psi$. In general, you can never distribute an existential over a conjunction. For example: $\exists x (Even(x) \land Odd(x))$ is not equivalent to $\exists x \ Even (x) \land \exists x \ Odd(x)$.  So no, your approach does not work .... it was a promising idea, but no, it doesn't work.

Comment: In case you haven't seen my previous message... Could you suggest me a text book which has explanation and example on how to solve those interpretations, please?

Comment: @Breno There are tons of these free and online. Here is one: https://www.fecundity.com/logic/download.html  (chapters 4 and 5)

Comment: Ok, @Bram28, are any of those interpretations true? Because I have done everything again and found out that none of them is true.
Is that correct?

Comment: @Breno  First, it would be good to add your work to your post: it shows effort, and we can comment on specific places where you might need some help. Anyway, I just looked at the first one, and that one is True: For any $x$, I can pick $y=x+1$ and $z=x$, and that will make everything true. Remember, any conditional is true as soon as the 'if' part (the antecedent) is false

Comment: Oh, I just got that wrong then... I will be posting my work, but first, let me ask you a question here...
Is that correct for any x, I can pick y=x+1? How come? Because to me that seems wrong... Because it should be valid to any value of x in the domain...
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Breno  OK, so for the 1st interpretation, you want to be able to pick a $y$ for every $x$ such that $x<y$. So, for example, if I pick $x=17$, you could pick $y=18$. If I pick $x=3$, you can pick $y=4$. If I pick $5352$, you can pick $y =5353$. Of course, you could have picked lots of other numbers in each case, but what will *always* work is for you to simply pick one higher for $y$ than whatever I pick for $x$. So yes, set $y = x+1$ and we're good!

Comment: I have posted my answers now, @Bram28, please take a look

Comment: @Breno Yes, all good now!